# Stepper Motor Button Press

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, button, stepper

I am having difficulties programming what should be a simple sketch that gets my **stepper motor to run at one step per second indefinitely at the press of a button and then stops at the press of another button.** I am using the *Bounce2.h* and *accelstepper.h* libraries and have been unable to figure out how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and as for hardware I am using a ***NEMA 23 High Torque Stepper Motor*** connected through a ***M542T Motor Driver*** powered by a ***Switching Power Supply*** and running on an ***Arduino UNO.***

Attatched find my code, and thank you so much for the help!

```
#include <Bounce2.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper(1, 9, 8); // initiate stepper motor

//int buttonPresses = 0;
const byte ButtonPin = 10;
const byte LedPin = 13; // for debugging and visualization

Bounce button;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  button.attach(ButtonPin);
  pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
  stepper.setSpeed(1);
}

void loop() {
  if (button.rose()) {
    stepper.runSpeed();
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
    //    buttonPresses++; // count presses of button and print to monitor
    //    Serial.print("Number of Button ");
    //    Serial.print("Presses = ");
    //    Serial.println(buttonPresses);
  }
  else {
    button.update();
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
    if (button.fell()) {
      stepper.stop();
    }
  }
}
```

**As of now, a button press runs the motor at 1 step/second, but a second press or any subsequent presses thereafter do nothing to stop the motor. Thanks so much!**

***!!EDIT!!***

Upon adding a boolean buttonState and setting it to LOW in the setup and changing my void loop() code to look like:

```
void loop() {
  button.update();
  if (button.rose() == true && buttonState == LOW) {
    stepper.runSpeed();
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
    buttonState = HIGH;
  }
  else {
    if (button.fell() == true && buttonState == HIGH) {
      stepper.stop();
      buttonState = LOW;
    }
  }
}
```

I know get a step every button press. Just thought it may help in answering.

**EDIT 2**

So I I tried pulling the runSpeed() out of the loop and adding                                                            `if (buttonState = HIGH){stepper.runSpeed();}` 
but that now just runs the stepperMotor constantly and at variable speed and will not turn it off?

**EDIT 3 and Working Code**
Thank you Janw for the help. I realized my fault in calling the runSpeed function within the if statement. Further, I also needed to change button.fell() to button.rose() since button.fell() returns true when the button is released, so basically I was stopping the motor everytime I let go of the button. Here is the final, and working void loop() in case anyone runs into a similar problem in the future:

```
void loop() {
  button.update();
  if (button.rose() == true && buttonState == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
    buttonState = HIGH;
  }
  else {
    if (button.rose() == true && buttonState == HIGH) {
      stepper.stop();
      buttonState = LOW;
    }
  }
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    stepper.setSpeed(1);
    stepper.runSpeed();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably get only 1 step each button press because your *runSpeed()* is within the *if (button.rose() == true && buttonState == LOW)*-statement.

The *runSpeed()* needs to be called every loop to check if the motor needs to step.

A simple way to change this is to set a boolean to true or false if you check your button and add something like this pseudocode:

```
if(motorRun == true) stepper.runSpeed();
```

Comment: check edits on initial question I have added some more!

Comment: You need == instead of =

Comment: Okay I'll try that and see if that does the trick! Thanks!